# CD player problem

Tags: 14.10, cd, cd-drive

I installed XUbuntu 14.10 (dual boot with Windows 7). When I tried to insert a CD, it didn't work (it works fine in Windows, though).

`sudo lshw`

```
*-scsi:1

physical id: 2

          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM UJ8B1
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: H.02
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: Did you install the restricted extras ? It contains some proprietary codecs needed to play certain types of files- sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: what is the cd? Is it DRM protected?

Comment: Any feed-back on above questions?

Comment: Could you add the output of `dmesg | tail -n 50` after you insert the CD into your question?

Comment: @helio Why did you put a bounty on this ? We did not even get feed back on the initial comments ?

Comment: @markkirby: I did because the only answer that had (currently removed) was awful.

Comment: OK, I never even saw an answer, but still, the OP never even responded to the first set of comments, restricted extras is the most common issue for stuff like this, did the OP already say that didn't work and I missed it ?

Comment: Do you use parole media player (the default), is this your error - :Could not handle CDDA URI:GStreamer backend error

Answer (score 2):

"status=nodisc" means there is no media in the drive. Double check that the disk is actually inserted and if not, do so. If so, try cleaning off the laser lens by removing the disk and blowing canned air into the drive, then reinserting the disk. If none of these approaches work, you likely either have a hardware problem or are missing some required software.

**Note: "works under Windows" tells me nothing as you haven't indicated whether it's on the same or different hardware.**

Once you've verified that it isn't a hardware problem, you may wish to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issue the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` If any of this is unclear or you are still unsuccessful edit your question and provide that information along with all else requested and drop me a comment and I'll clarify to the best of my ability.